# How can in print Facebook friend list from JSON FORMAT

Tags: php, arrays, json, facebook-graph-api, multidimensional-array

I m using codeigniter, in my view file

```
<?php 
$app_id = "APP_ID_HERE_XXXXXXXX";
$secret = "SECRET_XXXXXXXX";
$data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=friends&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$data = json_decode($data);
}
?>
```

**Problem:How can i print friend list from JSON data**

File Data After Decode Like This:

```
stdClass Object
(
[friends] => stdClass Object
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => frnd_name
                        [id] => frnd_id
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => frnd_name
                        [id] => frnd_id
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => frnd_name
                        [id] => frnd_id
                    )....
```

How can i print frnds name in list items..Thanx

Comment: can you post the json data, or part of it at least

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($data->friends->data as $friend){
   echo $friend->name." ".$friend->id."<br/>";
}
```